# Send ajax request at table cell change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I make a server request when the contect of a table cell is changed?

i.e. on a table like this:

```
<form class="formclass">
    <table border="1" style="float:left"> 
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="country" value="USA" readonly/></td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="enabled" value="1" checked>enabled
                <input type="radio" name="enabled" value="0">disable
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="country" value="England" readonly/></td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="enabled" value="1" checked>enabled
                <input type="radio" name="enabled" value="0">disable
            </td>
        </tr>                   
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="country" value="Sweden" readonly/></td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="enabled" value="1" checked>enabled
                <input type="radio" name="enabled" value="0">disable
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

I tried adding an onchange function

```
 $('.formclass').change(function() {console.log("succes")});
```

but this only works when every row is it's own form.

```
<form class="formclass">
    <table border="1" style="float:left"> 
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="country" value="USA" readonly/></td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="enabled" value="1" checked>enabled
                <input type="radio" name="enabled" value="0">disable
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>            
<form class="formclass">
    <table border="1" style="float:left"> 
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="country" value="Englang" readonly/></td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="enabled" value="1" checked>enabled
                <input type="radio" name="enabled" value="0">disable
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<form class="formclass">
    <table border="1" style="float:left">             
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="country" value="Sweden" readonly/></td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="enabled" value="1" checked>enabled
                <input type="radio" name="enabled" value="0">disable
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

However this makes the styling really bad.

I just want a table where if on cell is changed it makes a server request with the data of that row. So here the country and radio button value if someone changes the the radio button.

Comment: Hook to the `input` elements themselves, not the `form`.

Comment: Another issue: All radio buttons with the same name act as a group. Because you have one form (top example) the radio buttons are not isolated for each country.

Answer (score 0):

Attach it to inputs instead of form

```
 $('input[type=radio]').change(function() {console.log("succes")});
```